# References for (especially two-dimensional) general linear groups over *finite* fields

Tags: reference-request, finite-fields, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

**Questions.** What are good, citable, detailed sources on *general linear groups over **finite** fields*?  Especially, $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, and most especially, the following:

- characterization of *normalizers of tori in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$*, (I am sorry, but I can't get more specific about this rather special concern, for I want to play by the conventional rules of the reviewing process and not identify myself too much.)
- detailed classification of when an element $A\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is *diagonalizable*. There seem to be detailed results on what field-extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$ the eigenvalues of diagonalizable $A\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ can possibly lie in (this I infer from the assertions I have to check), but within the time I took during a reviewing job, I did not find a good reference. Algebraically closed fields dominate the literature, needless to say,
- characterization of all elements of $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ which have order equal to $p$,
- classification of the *intersection of two distinct tori* in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

**Remarks.** Motivation for this reference requestion is that---in a mostly combinatorial article that I am tasked with reviewing---on one page, all of a sudden, I am confronted is a barrage of non-trivial (though no doubt known to experts) assertions about general linear groups over *finite* fields. (They are using these statements en route to another result.) It is strange, and somewhat reproachable, that the authors do not give a single reference for their statements, writing as if this was an article in a professional algebra journal.

Comment: If you don't want to identify yourself, perhaps change your username ? (sorry I can't help you with the question though)

Comment: @Max: thanks for the suggestion; it's not that sensitive; my question is obfuscated enough; besides, there are circumstances which make this reviewing task a particularly relaxed matter. I'm not comfortable saying more. I am looking for a specialized reference on general linear, and projective linear, groups over finite fields. They are only a side show in a longer combinatorial paper though.

Comment: Would you be interested in solutions to the issues you ask about, or only references?

Comment: Dear @KReiser: thanks for asking; for rather emotional reasons I would prefer to only be pointed to good specialized references (strangely, despite knowing how to search the literature rather well, I did not find anything even close to a book which would contain lots of results on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p$). If I would give the statements explicitly, I would feel as if I would let someone else do the reviewing-job I am tasked with. Rather, I am looking for sources which could roughly be described 'as much information as possible beyond what one gets by simply reading the usual theory of..

Comment: ..diagonalizable endomorphism while replacing every general field (or PID) with $\mathbb{F}_p$. In my education, diagonalizability-theory for modules over PID was the most general I encountered; in this case, this seems not to help much (even though any field trivially is a PID of course), for the authors seem to use (without reference, as if this was common knowledge), some classification result for the eigenvalues of a diagonalizable element of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$. I am looking for sources containing such specialized results, something like 'what can be said on diagonalizablilty..

Comment: ..over finite fields, *over and above* what one gets from the usual general theory (results like 'diag. iff minimal polynomial splits into linear factors'). Independent of this, I could also use articles/books/websites on classifications of elements of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ according to their *order* in the group.

Comment: Everything you want falls out of Jordan normal form, Cayley-Hamilton, and some very basic finite field theory. C-H gives that the eigenvalues (if they exist) are either both in $\Bbb F_p$ or $\Bbb F_{p^2}$, so the matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ iff it's diagonalizable. If not, it's similar to a Jordan block with diag entries in $\Bbb F_p$. Nondiag'ble elts have order $p$, diag'ble over $\Bbb F_p$ have order dividing $p-1$, and diag'ble elts over $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ have order dividing $p^2-1$ but not $p-1$ because the Frobenius is the unique element of the Galois group...

Comment: ... and all of these matrix computations can be performed by hand without too much trouble. I think they're probably on MO or MSE somewhere, too. For the bits regarding tori, most introductory Lie theory books should have the classification of normalizers of (diagonal) tori in them, and those proofs should be able to be phrased without reliance on characteristic. I would also suggest that you ask your authors to include the citations for this in their paper, or failing that, include the results so that others may cite _their_ paper.

Comment: @KReiser: thank you very much, this seems to set me on the right track.